# ggplot smoothing in R - interpretation

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

[Count of words over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W1JT.jpg)

I created the following plot in R with this code:

```
          ggplot(sentiment, aes(x = year, y = nrc_sent$sentiment)) + 
        geom_smooth(method = "auto") +  # pick a method & fit a model
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(sentiment$year), max(sentiment$year), by = 2),1))+
        labs(x="", y="")
```

`geom_smooth()` `using method = 'loess'`(Got this message when running the code)

Where `nrc_sent` represents

`> nrc_sent`
`# A tibble: 519 x 3`
`sentiment state    year`
         `<dbl> <chr> <dbl>`
`1 152. Alabama 2007.`
 `2 107. Alabama 2008.`
 `3 80. Alabama 2009.`
 `4 75. Alabama 2010.`
 `5 173. Alabama 2011.`
 `6 180. Alabama 2012.`
 `7 187. Alabama 2013.`
 `8 167. Alabama 2014.`
 `9 124. Alabama 2015.`
`10 215. Alabama 2016.`
`# ... with 509 more rows`

I am puzzled as to what the shaded area around the line represents. I looked into ggplot help [page](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html), but there does not seem to be any information that I can use in my academic article to explain what the graph represents, and what the shaded area is. I would appreciate any help with this

Comment: It's a confidence interval.  There should be a way to control the confidence levels.  I could look for it.  The option might be called "levels."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for geom_smooth: `?geom_smooth` , it states that the parameter `se` is used to control if there is a confidence interval around the fitted line.  If it is `TRUE` then you are instructed to look at `level` `level` is the level of confidence interval to use with a default of 0.95.

My guess is this will also work for you.  True playing with the level.

```
ggplot(sentiment, aes(x = year, y = nrc_sent$sentiment)) + 
        geom_smooth(method = "loess", se=TRUE,level=0.95) +  # pick a method & fit a model
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(sentiment$year), max(sentiment$year), by = 2),1))+
        labs(x="", y="")
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work (even without `se=TRUE`)! Now i can say that it is confidence interval. Do you know or could you guide me somewhere I can read on how exactly the smoothing is calculated? I would want to understand that too.

Comment: @Michael, `method="loess"` refers to this fitting model: `?loess`